# Two body problem (rotation around a fixed central point)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, circles, rotations, mathematical-astronomy

Is there a way which isn't physics related, but just using pure maths to find the solution to the following problem:

If i have two lines of different lengths at t=0 overlapping each other. They are both fixed at a central point and will rotate at different speeds so they're bound to overlap at some point. Knowing the length of these two lines and the respective velocities, how can I find the distance or the time at which the angle between the two is zero once again (so they overlap once again). I've tried circular motion and related rates of change but can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: The two lines extend in both directions from their common fixed point of rotation? Or just in one direction?

Comment: Sorry thought I mentioned it but know they're not infinite because I know their lengths. Context is of two different planets around the sun in a circular orbit. So their respective orbits have their own radius which is finite right? I'm trying to find an alternative method from circular motion to try and find the point at which these two planets overlap if they start their rotation from a point of overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, suppose the two planets rotate with angular velocities $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$. Measure angles from the direction at time $t = 0$ used as the zero. Then at time $t$ the two planets are at positions $\omega_1t$ and $\omega_2t$. These two are equal iff

$$\omega_1 t - \omega_2 t = 2n\pi, \ \ \ \hbox{ for some integer } n$$

Now you should be able to find all such times $t$.

Comment: Thank you sir! Is there any other mathematical method I could investigate in order to provide an alternative method of solution? Something in line with the maths syllabus taught in college because this method even though is absolutely brilliant is leaning a little towards the physics right? Is there no possible way of pure maths to solve this problem? Sorry for being a hassle

Comment: This is purely mathematical. To dress it up a little, the two are equal iff

$$\omega_1 t \equiv \omega_2 t \mod 2\pi$$

The formula above is just rewriting this one.

Comment: Hello Simon sir. Can you help me in finding out a method to find the time that more than two objects overlap? So if say three objects were going in an orbit around a common point at different velocities and radius's how can I find the time at which they overlap? Thanks in advance!